# How to restart nut upsd service in Synology DSM7 command line

Tags: command-line, synology

After adding additional NUT UPS (Uninterruptible Power Supply) users to `/etc/ups/upsd.users` to Synology NAS in order to get access from Linux servers connected to same ups, you need to restart ups server.

If you do not want to reboot all Synology DSM7 NAS, you should restart NUT upsd service, but there is no documentation, on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, when you know the details.

In DSM7 service control is handled by command `synosystemctl`. The service, responsible for UPS is not easy guess, it's called `ups-usb`.

To restart UPS service just run:

```
synosystemctl restart ups-usb
```

For DSM6 this would be:

```
synoservice --restart ups-usb
```

Hope it will save time for some folks.